# Do I have to be an expert to propose a SE 2.0 site?

Tags: support, area-51

If I propose a Stack Exchange 2.0 site, do I need to be an expert in that field? Should I be?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Area51 proposals; it would be on-topic on the [Area 51 discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is encouraged.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)

> **How do I start a new site?**
>
> If your **area of expertise** doesn’t already have a Stack Exchange site, propose it here. Stack Exchange sites are free to create and free to use. All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed **group of expert users** who will check in regularly, asking and answering questions.

Comment: Guess I can give up my proposal then... :P